# Как бот может вынести значение, которое требует юзер, из Excel таблицы? PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, excel, telebot

Создаю телеграм бота (библиотека pytelegrambotapi). Допустим, бот связан с мебелью, а этой мебели 200 штук и писать if-elif-else, словари и т.д. очень долго и неудобно. Поэтому решил подключить к работе Excel таблицу (впервые с ним работаю, выбрал библиотеку xlrd, если библиотека выбрана не так, как надо, то прошу сообщить мне!).

Есть заголовки столбцов: название, материал, высота, ширина.

И должно выглядить вот так:

Юзер: "Пишет название мебели"

Бот: *берет всю инфу об ЭТОЙ мебели, кроме названия*

Бот: *Выводит* "Высота: х см., ширина у см., материал такой-то"

Возможно ли такое реализовать? Есть ли примеры? Примеров вообще не нашел в гугле. Заранее спасибо громадное))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, реализовать такое можно, но использовать для этих целей Excel - не лучшая идея. Почему? `.xls` это простой файл, считывание таких файлов относительно медленная операция, особенно с учетом того, что считывание экселя обычно значительно замедляется при увеличении количества данных (а что если у вас будет 10000 наименований мебели?) а так же с учетом того, что библиотека, которая его читает должна кроме прочего спарсить такой файл в удобный для работы в питоне объект (например в словарь или список). Такая задача, возможно, требует другого подхода.

Возможно вы скажете, что в вашей текущей задаче такой проблемы не появится, но ведь этот ответ в Т.Ч. для будущих поколений и для помощи вам в решении будущих задач :)

Теоретически (если вашей мебели действительно всего +-200 экземпляров) можно хранить всё в `Json` файле, примерно так:

```json
[     
    {
        "name": "Черный стол",
        "sizes": "100x200x300",
        "color": "black",
        "description": "самый лучший стол"
    },
    {
        "name": "Синий стул",
        "sizes": "146x300x69",
        "color": "blue",
        "description": "самый лучший стул для лучшего стола"
    },
    {
        "name": "Шкаф",
        "sizes": "2x2",
        "color": "purple",
        "description": "Кто вообще заказал фиолетовый шкаф?"
    }
]
```

Для работы с `Json` в Python есть готовый модуль `json`, а его считывание, запись и парсинг происходят весьма быстро, но такой подход все ещё будет не очень хорошо работать для большого количества данных, хотя к преимуществам можно отнести возможность создания произвольной структуры:
Для каждой мебели вы можете указывать те поля, которые хотите, например сделать объект без поля `цвет`, без описания, или добавить к шкафу параметр наличия отдельной антресоли.

Однако раз (судя по вашему вопросу) вы имеете четкую структуру описания каждого объекта, возможно данное "преимущество" вам не нужно, тогда вы можете прибегнуть к более традиционному способу: использовать `Базу данных`

База данных имеет много преимуществ, к основным можно отнести следующие:

- Высокая скорость работы (относительно прошлых способов)
- Возможность общего доступа (например если кроме вашего бота информацию из неё будет читать ещё ваш сайт, или если вы захотите подключиться к ней из вне и внести изменения) Согласитесь, удобнее зайти в браузер и поменять всё оттуда, а не подключаться к файловой системе сервера, открывать файл, копировать, вставлять и т.д.
- Определение правил безопасности (В базе данных можно легко ограничить права разных пользователей, например, чтобы вы могли вносить любые правки, а ваш менеджер мог лишь смотреть на них)
- Определение связей данных (например, если вы хотите всегда знать к какому шкафу в комплекте идет данная антресоль, или к какому кухонному комплекту можно заказать в комплекте данный стол.

Более подробно о преимуществах вы можете узнать в интернете :)

Я же попробую показать пример кода работы с `sqlite3` базой данных. Она имеет много ограничений, в сравнении с более "правильным" базами данных, такими как `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle` и т.п. Но имеет очень важное преимущество: она не требует дополнительных настроек и установок, а её использование достаточно просто, например Python имеет встроенный модуль для работы с `sqlite3` базами данных, в то время как для работы с `postgreSQL` понадобится установка дополнительных библиотек, например `psycopg2`.

Попробую представить небольшой фрагмент (Очень упрощенный) Создания базы данных и добавления в неё информации:

```py
import sqlite3 as sl

con = sl.connect('furniture.db')
try:
    with con:
        con.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE furniture (
                id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                name VARCHAR(255),
                size VARCHAR(255),
                color VARCHAR(255),
                description TEXT
            );
        """)
except sl.OperationalError:
    print('База данных уже создана. Пропускаем этот этап')

# Записываем в базу какие-то записи
sql = 'INSERT INTO furniture (name, size, color, description) values( ?, ?, ?, ?)'
data = [ 
    ('Черный стол', '100x200x300', 'black', 'самый лучший стол'),
    ('Синий стул', '146x300x69', 'blue', 'самый лучший стул для лучшего стола'),
    ('Шкаф', '2x2', 'purple', 'Кто вообще заказал фиолетовый шкаф?')
]  # data Может быть любыми вашими записями, как вы их запишите, это лишь ваше дело
with con:
    con.executemany(sql, data)
```

Надеюсь пока не слишком сложно? После запуска данного кода в базе мы увидим следующую картину:
[image]

Сразу отвечу на возможно возникший вопрос тех, кто впервые столкнулся с базами данных, и не понимает, что это за странные буквы аля `CREATE TABLE` - это специальный язык `SQL`. Почти все реляционные базы данных (например все упомянутые выше) управляются при помощи этого языка, не стоит пугаться раньше времени, основы его очень просты [например здесь](https://proglib.io/p/sql-for-20-minutes) можно изучить весь основной синтаксис за 20 минут.

Скорее всего, запуск данного кода, с заполнением базы данных вы хотите выполнять редко: при поступлении новых товаров, например раз в неделю. В остальное время вам, скорее всего нужно будет читать содержимое. Давайте рассмотрим пример:

Вот так можно сделать чтение всех записей из таблицы:

```py
import sqlite3 as sl

con = sl.connect('furniture.db')

with con:
    data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM furniture")
    for row in data:
        print(f'{row[4]} размером {row[2]} и с цветом "{row[3]}"')
```

Согласитесь, не очень сложно?

Вот что мы получим в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как известно простое правило гласит:

*Всё что можно вывести в консоль, можно вывести и в telegram бота.*

Но ведь нам нужно получать только конкретную мебель по названию? Да без проблем:

```py
import sqlite3 as sl

con = sl.connect('furniture.db')

furniture_name = 'Черный стол'

with con:
    data = con.execute("SELECT * FROM furniture WHERE name=?", [furniture_name])
    res = data.fetchone()
    if not res:
        print('Мебель не найдена')
    else:
        print(res)
```

При этом в выводе мы увидим всю информацию об искомом столе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при этом логику вы можете легко подстроить под себя: находить только те модели, которые есть на складе, возможно пользователь захочет увидеть всю черную мебель и т.д. всю логику фильтрации (если вы сделаете её при помощи SQL) будет брать на себя БД, а она делает это куда быстрее питона (хорошо видно на большом количестве записей)

Но вы же всё-таки спрашивали про Excel, и я говорил, что можно сделать через excel? Ну, за слова надо отвечать. Вот так выглядит мой excel файл:
[image: excel]

А вот как выглядит его считывание:

```py
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile('db.xlsx')

df1 = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0])
hist_data = df1.to_numpy().tolist()

for el in hist_data:
    print(el)
```

[image: результат]

Сразу оговорись, я использую `pandas` и `openpyxl`, потому что новые `.xlsx` файлы библиотека `xlrd` обрабатывать не умеет.

Вам может показаться, что данный скрипт куда проще, Но за это приходится дорого платить: В то время как скрипт читающий записи из базы у меня выполняется ~0.3 секунды, этот уже целых 2! И будьте уверены, чем больше будет записей, тем больше будет разрыв.

Более того, скрипт записи отрабатывает ещё дольше, около 3х секунд:

```py
import pandas as pd

#xl = pd.ExcelFile('db1.xlsx', )
data = [
    [1, 'Черный стол', '100x200x300', 'black', 'самый лучший стол'],
    [2, 'Синий стул', '146x300x69', 'blue', 'самый лучший стул для лучшего стола'],
    [3, 'Шкаф', '2x2', 'purple', 'Кто вообще заказал фиолетовый шкаф?']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.transpose()
df.to_excel('db.xlsx')
```

Но при его работе получается другая структура документа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А значит, нужно либо учитывать это при считывании, либо изменять структуру получаемого файла под себя. Причем я, например, не смог в приемлемые сроки найти в интернете понятный гайд, как это сделать. Хотя нужные мне подсказки по работой с базе данных я нашел по первым же ссылкам.

Да, возможно есть и более быстрые способы работы с Excel, но они, очевидно, будут более сложными и менее понятными.

Исходя из всего выше перечисленного, как я уже сказал, для таких целей **нужно** использовать базу данных, ведь именно для этого они и придуманы.

Comment: Великолепно! Вы так хорошо объяснили, что даже я, создающий впервые всё это и почти не сильно хорошо разбираюсь в библиотеках и БД, понял с первого раза! Я обязательно сохраню свой вопрос  с Вашим ответом, чтобы другие люди смогли разобраться тоже! Спасибо Вам большое! Но, есть один нюансик у меня. Я программирую на смартфона... А это, довольно-таки, плохо, так как возможностей мало. Смогу ли я использовать вашу предложенную БД? (Sqlite, как я читал, вроде недоступен)

Comment: Когда я в последний раз пробовал, была интересная программа - PyDroid3. В ней была и подсветка синтаксиса, и установка практически любых библиотек, и вроде работа с sqlite тоже была доступна. Если же всё-таки нет (в чем я очень сильно сомневаюсь), то вы можете попробовать настроить подключение к удалённой (работающей на отдельном компьютере) базе данных, например PostgreSQL. Работать с ней несколько сложнее, чем с sqlite, но я уверен, вы справитесь :) хотя я бы всё-таки оаетовал переходить на компьютер

Comment: Как раз на нем программирую (Pydroid3)! Тогда всё ясно. Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте **[sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)** вместо exel таблиц, если данные должны храниться локально. Если же у вас SQL сервер в облаке, используйте **[PyMySQL](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)**.

Comment: Забыл уточнить... Я занимаюсь созданием тг бота на смартфоне... Конечно, очень мала вероятность создания на мобильном гаджете, но, всё-таки решил попробовать... Но, обязательно учу ваш комментарий